# Validate cell and get grade

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my requirement. I have sheet in which column B has marks. Based on the marks and with a click of a button, I'm trying to get grades and colour the cell based on grade. Following is the code I wrote but this is not successfully working. Kindly, help

```
Sub SetGrade()
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim Score As Double

    For r = 2 To 20
        Score = Cells(r, 2).Value

        If Score >= 90 And Score <= 100 Then
            ActiveCell(1, 2).Value = "A"
            ActiveCell(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            ActiveCell(1, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        ElseIf Score >= 75 And Score <= 90 Then
            ActiveCell(1, 2).Value = "B"
            ActiveCell(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
            ActiveCell(1, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you actually need to do is get rid of the activecell like this:

```
Sub SetGrade()
Dim r As Integer
Dim Score As Double

For r = 2 To 20

Score = Cells(r, 2).Value

If Score >= 90 And Score <= 100 Then

    Cells(r, 3).Value = "A"
    Cells(r, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Cells(r, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

ElseIf Score >= 75 And Score <= 90 Then

    Cells(r, 3).Value = "B"
    Cells(r, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    Cells(r, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

End If

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ You beat me to it :)